# Saving Texture2D to JPEG

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cocos2d-iphone, image-conversion

i was wondering if its possible to save texture2d to jpeg without using texture2d.saveAsJpeg method, as its memory leaking?

(not the ImageTools Solution - because I'm using cocos-2d)

Comment: Why, does the ImageTools solution not work for you?

Comment: because i'm using cocos-2d :-)

Comment: Then please add that tag to your question or otherwise edit it. Edit: Did it for you.